# Connect Oracle Database 12c via SQL Developer when it is in restricted mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, connections, listener, tnsnames

I would like to connect to database 12c via SQL Developer(in same VM where db is hosted) when it is in restrict mode. Tried below approaches but nothing worked.
Kindly help !

1. Added (UR=A) in tnsname.ora as below:
   OBIEE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.37)(PORT = 1522))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.37)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (UR=A)
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = OBIEE)
   )
   )
2. Also, defined this in sqlnet.ora:
   tcp.validnode_checking = YES
   tcp.invited_nodes = IP address

*Note: I am able to connect to it via cmd.

Comment: SQL Developer is probably going through the listener... Is the listener up? Also, are you connecting as sysdba? If so what is parameter remote_login_passwordfile set to?

Answer (score 1):

The above connection string should work with the addition of `(UR=A)`. Seems like your SQL Developer connection is configured differently.

Alternatively, you can define the connection type as `Advanced`, and use the below custom JDBC url:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.37)(PORT = 1522)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.37)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (UR=A) (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = OBIEE) ) )
```